# Can I use Force Push or similar force powers without killing the opponent?

Tags: damage, star-wars-saga-edition

I have a Jedi character in a Star Wars Saga edition game, who does not want to kill without good reason.
If he uses a force power like Force Push, it causes a set amount of damage which usually kills the opponent.
Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Comment: I don't know the system, so just asking as a comment: Have you talked to your GM about that?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of **Force Push**, you could use:

> **Force Thrust:** You use the force to push a target away from you. (Saga Edition Core Rule Book, p. 98)

There is a nice little [Non-Lethal Force Powers Index](http://kotor.griffcrier.com/bookshelf/non-lethal-force-powers-index/) that should be able to help you out.

---

As far as using lethal force powers and not dealing damage, or reduced damage, that would entirely rest upon your GM's shoulders. There isn't a mechanic available that allows for such a thing (to the best of my knowledge). If I were GM, I would probably allow Force Points to vary your damage dealt, rather than increasing your d20 roll, depending on what your intentions were. Speak with your GM about this, he will in fact be the arbiter of such a thing.

Comment: "If I were GM, I would probably increase the power cost by a few points depending on what your intentions were." This is an odd statement, considering Force Powers in Saga Edition are like Encounter Powers from 4e D&D. Generally there is no cost to using them, though you can use Force Points to make them more effective. You either have a particular power in your suite of available powers for that encounter, or you don't. Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: @Dyndrilliac Instead of using Force Points to modify your die roll by Xd6, use Force Points to do X amount of damage less or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to augment force powers to deal less damage by RAW; the only way to deal less damage would be get your GM to implement a houserule.  There are many force powers that don't deal damage and instead move the opponent down the condition track, which is the best route to go for force powers if you don't like killing enemies and can be vastly more efficient than just augmenting a force power to deal less damage if you have an amazing use the force check.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a reference handy, but the devs clarified years ago that force powers can *always* be 'dialed down' to avoid killing someone with them.